# mixing numbers in hikashop's total price

Tags: joomla-3.6, hikashop

when someone purchase an order in my website,price numbers in total price part after purchase will be mixed for example :
 total price is 10000 will changed to 00010
i am using Persian font in my website but my only problem is with total prices.
i am using Hikashop for my online shop in joomla 3.6.2
can anyone help me plzzzzzz.

Comment: you need to ask this question on the Hikashop forum, the Hikashop team are much more qualified to answer this kind of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your currency via the menu System>Currencies and remove the space in the "Groups separation" setting there.
That will prevent your prices groups of digits from switching positions when your language is RTL like with Persian.

Comment: it was great answer thanks.my problem solved.